# How to set website id as 1 for all products in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product

We have 200 products in our existing Magento website and there more are made in them. Can anyone please let me how can we set website id as 1 for all existing and as well as new products in Magento.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **mass edit** feature for it.

```
Go to Catalog > Manage Products
```

Select All Products and from Mass Actions select **Update Attributes**

Select The **WebSites Tab** From here its easy to manage for which website you want to add products or remove them.

**Edited**

You can use observer to set website Id So every product can be saved to default website id

Event to Use keep in your **config.xml**

Path: Namespace/Modulename/etc/config.xml

```
<events>
    <catalog_product_save_before>
        <observers>
            <product_set_website>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>Namespace_Modulename_Model_Adminhtml_Observer</class>
                <method>saveWebsiteId</method>
            </product_set_website>
        </observers>
    </catalog_product_save_before>   
</events>
```

**Observer.php**

Path: Namespace/Modulename/Model/Adminhtml/Observer.php

```
class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Adminhtml_Observer{

    public function saveWebsiteId($observer){
        $product = $observer->getProduct();        
        $product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: thank for your reply, but i want this for all new products as well,  so is there is any way we can edit magento php files for this, where we can set website id as 1?

Comment: Check My Updated Answer

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you please tell me the path of these two files, as there are so many config.xml and Observer.php files.  Thank you in Advance userpk

Comment: You need to create a module for it (app/code/local/) and then follow the above path as mentioned above. If you don't know how to create a module google it tons of reference is available.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this simply from Admin Panel.

1. Just check all products from the grid view
2. select mass-action "Update attributes" and in the next step select website.
3. For new products - you always need to choose website. It's part of product creation process.

Comment: but is there any way we can do it by editing any php or phtml files, i mean magento files.